# How might one recreate an image, e.g., .png or .jpg, using only web tech, e.g., HTML, CSS, and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, svg

I'm interested in taking an image of any of the typical formats, e.g., PNG, JPEG, et cetera, and recreating it as a group of arranged, individually colored, 1 by 1 pixel HTML elements, or something like that. I want to be able to work with, i.e., style and script (movement, color change, et cetera), the individual pixels of an image. How might I achieve this? SVG comes to mind, but I'm not familiar enough with it to now if it's where I ought to be looking.

Comment: Why not draw it on a `canvas` instead? Canvas is a web technology that's implemented as an HTML tag and accessed via JavaScript. You can recreate images pixel by pixel with it.

Comment: Canvas, not SVG. Recreating a picture in SVG on pixel level would be extremely memory-intensive, slow and painful. Also, stating the purpose might give you more helpful answers.

Comment: As correctly mentioned in the comments, Canvas can do what you require. Canvas can display your image using context.drawImage and you can manipulate each pixel on the canvas using context.getImageData. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using canvas can help draw images using the three languages you named. 
For example:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100"
style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>

<script>
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,75);
</script>
```

This can create a red square within a box.
You can also create circles using

```
ctx.arc();
ctx.stroke();
```

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp They also give you a great amount of items in good detail to use each of the canvas methods.

Hope this is what you are looking for!